# Authentication failed while using git push

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I'm using an aplication called Gitora that creates a repository Git with objects from an oracle database. I clone that repo to tortoise and work with the files there. The problem is that when I Push the changes, it asks me for credentials. I put the correct credentials (I checked) but keeps giving me this error

Comment: the error you get ssh key permission denied or it complains ssh authentication failed or you're using HTTP protocol?

Comment: Well, I think I'm using HTTP protocol, and I also didn't config any ssh key...

Comment: whats your push command? and url?

Answer (score 0):

You can check your credential's permission on git server, which could be caused by read-only permission problem I thought.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this answer. It might be your server does not provide write permission over http. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24572857/1084174

Comment: Using git instead of http gives me "Fatal: Could not read from remote repository". Also most of the solutions I check are related to putting the SSH key into Github, but the aplication seems to use Gitlit.